# Why is my log out link going off the edge of the screen?

Tags: css, header, html-lists, stylesheet, display

I’m trying to right align navigation links to the right of my header section.  So I created

```
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">My Subscriptions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
```

and added this style

```
header ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

header ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

But my Log Out link is going off the edge of the screen — https://jsfiddle.net/p2rwgfjc/ .  How can I modify this so that all the text stays on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `margin-right: 15px` to your `header ul`.

```
header ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/og165aky/

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the width of block is include the default padding ,and you have set the 100% width of header, so the total width of header is greater than 100% and going off the edge of the screen.
So you should clear the default margin and padding of the block .
The most convenient way is by * {padding: 0, margin: 0}. 
I hope this answer can help you !

Comment: Where am I putting "{padding: 0, margin: 0}"?  Also am I removing anything?

Comment: In general, we will remove the all default padding and margin by  * {padding:0; margin: 0} in css .  the  ' * ' is a css selector that can selector all elements . So , when you selected the all elements, you can clear them .

Answer (score 0):

I think when you float something, you have to float its parent as well otherwise the the element that you have floated leaves the other html elements structure and becomes a separate element floating around.

So float the parent element and give it a float of none or inherit.

Answer (score 0):

1. forget about float.
2. mind your wrapper width.
3. using flex on your wrapper.
4. using flex on your UL.

```css
header{
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #44505d;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 73px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.wrapperLogo{
width:30%;}

header nav{
width:70%;}


#logo {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


#logo:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header ul {
  list-style: none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```html
<header id="branding" class="clearFix">
  <div class="wrapperLogo">
    <a id="logo" href="#">sample app</a>
  </div>
 <nav>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">My Subscriptions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    <li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

it's not perfect, yes of course. you need to modify the mobile view also. like font and width and height. etc.

look at this one

> ```
>  header ul {
>       list-style: none;
>       display:flex;
>       justify-content:space-around;
>     }
> ```

you can modify it without justify content or you can delete it also and change it  with your previous css `header ul li {margin-left:15px}`

Comment: Although your "Log Out" link is visible, the links seem centerd and I want to align them to the right with only a little space between them.  How would I do taht?